# How to add type to error message on Future

Tags: scala, future

I write to a database in a simple function that returns a Future of the list that has been written to the database.

```scala
def writeToDB(db:Database, items: List[(String,String)]) = {
   Future {
      db.writeAsync(items) // Returns Unit
      items
   }
}

val res: Future[List[(String,String)]] = writeToDB(someItems)
```

On `Success` I have access to the written items so I can report which items have been written. But on `Failure`, in case the database fails, I don't have access to the failed items (e.g. for retry, for reporting and ...).

Is there any way to capture the `items` in error, something like `Either` that has `Success(items)` and `Failure(items)`?

Comment: Other option would be to use a `Future[Either[E, A]` or the same as a `EitherT[Future, E, A]`

Answer (score 4):

Because Scala's `Future` is essentially an asynchronous `Try`, failure has to be encoded as a `Throwable` (most likely as an `Exception`).  One way to encode the failure to write an item to the DB is via

```
case class DBFailedToWriteItem(items: Seq[(String, String)], cause: Throwable) extends Exception("Failed to write item to database", cause)

def writeToDB(db: Database, items: Seq[(String, String)]): Future[Seq[(String, String)]] =
  Future { db.writeAsync(items) }
    .map { _ => items }
    .recoverWith {
      case NonFatal(e) => Future.failed(DBFailedToWriteItem(items, e))
    }
```

`.recoverWith` allows you to transform a failed `Future` into an arbitrary (either failed or successful) `Future`.  The `scala.util.control.NonFatal` extractor prevents it from transforming certain failures which it's not reasonable to transform (generally ones that indicate the JVM is irretrievably hosed); I forget if `recoverWith` and friends implicitly perform this exclusion, so the match might be a bit of "belt and suspenders".

That said, I'm curious regarding the interface exposed by `Database`.  If `db.writeAsync` is async, it's kind of odd for it to return `Unit` without giving the opportunity to attach a callback.  The API seems to imply that it will catch a failure to set up the write, but not a failure to complete the write.

EDIT to add: from a comment, `db.writeAsync` returns a `CompletableFuture` (which is also a `CompletionStage`, Java's future API does not observe the read/write separation that Scala's does). You can use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat)'s `scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters` to convert a `CompletionStage` into a `Future`.

```
sealed trait DBFailed

def writeToDB(db: Database, items: Seq[(String, String)]): Future[Either[DBFailed, Seq[(String, String)]]] = {
  import scala.compat.java8.FutureConverters.toScala

  toScala(db.writeAsync(items))
    .map { _ => Right(items) }
    .recover {
      case NonFatal(e) => Left(???)  // create an appropriate 
                                     //  DBFailed... you can also 
                                     //  pattern match on the 
                                     //  particular exception from 
                                     //  db.writeAsync
    }
}
```

Note that with `Either` the convention is for the failure case to be the left (first) subtype and the success to be the right.  Since Scala 2.12, this convention is encouraged by right-biasing `Either`:

```
val either: Either[String, Int] = ???
val rightTransform: Either[String, Double] = either.map(_.toDouble + 42.0)
val leftTransform: Either[Option[Char], Int] = either.left.map( _.headOption)
```

Comment: I kinda simplified it. I'm working with FoundationDB Java API and it gets a CompletableFuture.
The type of the writeToDB should become something like `Future[Either[Sucess...,Fail..]]` I guess I can use items and when mapping the Future create `Future[Either[List[...], DBFailed]]` , right? Actually I don't have access to Sucess and Failure in the map.

Comment: I've edited my answer to correct falling-back into `Try` and with a skeleton to convert a `CompletableFuture` to a Scala `Future[Either[DBFailed, Seq[(String, String)]]`

Comment: I ended up using `transformWith` and used Future.successful for both cases to transform it to Future[Either[... , ...]. If you can add that to your answer as well it would be great.